# SFTP for Customers

Tags: linux, windows-server-2003, sftp

We would like to setup SFTP on windows server 2003 in such a way that all our customers (approx. 15 users) can have their own download/upload shares (without creating users in windows domain). We must also have public key authentication.

I've looked at Filezilla but this doesn't have support for windows server 2003. Any other free software/low cost software that will allow this?

We rather not go into Linux to provide SFTP through SSH but if we have to what would be the preferred method of setup without creating a new user account for each share? Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[CompleteFTP](http://enterprisedt.com/products/completeftp/) starts at $249 for the Standard Edition, which should cover your requirements.  It allows you to create users inside the package itself without having to create Windows users for them.  There's also a virtual file-system allowing you to customize the directory structure that you present to users.  It supports Windows Server 2003.  There are also Professional Edition and Enterprise Editions.  They offer many more advanced features, which you shouldn't need now, but you have the option of upgrading later on.  I'm one of the developers of this software.